# How to find scholarly articles related to Latin?

Tags: resource-request, soft-question, study-strategies

If I want to find research articles of some kind to learn more about a particular topic related to Latin, what should I do?
I am a trained scientist, but my own research is on a very different field.

If I want to find mathematical articles, it is often best to use [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) or [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/).
The latter requires subscription but the database is very comprehensive and the reviews are useful.
The former is a preprint server where many mathematicians and physicists make their work freely available when they submit to a journal, making the articles readable long before the review process is complete.
Sometimes [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) is useful and it includes all fields, but I find it somewhat unreliable or inconsistent.

I am looking for a high level overview of how to find articles.
What do researchers in Latin language, archaeology, history, literature and similar fields actually do when they want to read about something new?
If there are numerous useful online services or the approach depends heavily on circumstances (for example being at a university or not) or the precise field, please indicate so.
In that case more specific questions need to be asked later on to understand the details.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to tag this. Any ideas are welcome, either here or in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm).

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can suggest is to become a regular reader of the standard specialist journals. A good start would be with these ones:

https://www.jstor.org/publisher/classical

Answer (score 2):

Subscription only (available mostly to institutions):

- [Brill Online Reference Works](http://brillonline.nl/)
- [De Gruyter](http://www.degruyter.com/browse?t1=LS) (includes [Journal of Latin Linguistics](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/joll) and excellent [New Perspectives on Historical Latin Syntax](http://www.degruyter.com/view/serial/35156?rskey=HleFLn&result=1) four-volume series, among other things)
- [John Benjamins](http://www.jbe-platform.com/content/lin;jsessionid=28e5q9q1cr5k8.x-jbep-live-01)
- [Oxford Scholarship Online](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/browse?t=OSO:classics)
- databases, like ProQuest and EBSCO

Free: [Academia](https://www.academia.edu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to a site like [CiteULike](http://citeulike.org) and look for items tagged "latin" or and follow the links there.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of articles about biology interferring the result. You can refine the result set using advance search.

P.S. Entering "latin language" into Google Scholar's search slit didn't look that bad to me. ("latin" alone has many distractions like "latin america" or "latin square")