# What have we learned about Latin in the last century?

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request, soft-question

I have studied Latin, but in none of the courses I have taken has there been discussion about any progress in understanding Latin.
I do believe — and hope — that classically oriented scholarly activities have produced new insights in the last century, but I am not aware of any such developments.

**What is the biggest single step we have taken or the most important new insight we have gained in understanding the classical Latin language after the year 1900?**
This is a matter of opinion to some extent, but I would like to know what Latinists have achieved and why those achievements are considered important.
There are books and [scientific articles](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1515/79) about Latin, but it is very difficult and time consuming for a non-expert to locate important new ideas and figure out if there is a consensus behind them.
I am looking for something that is supported by a broad consensus or is even considered a fact, not hotly contested theories.

Although I probably would enjoy a summary of all developments, I believe this question is more focused when I ask for the single most important development.
This question type is somewhat experimental; let me know if you have comments about its broadness and suitability.

Comment: I assume you are purposely restricting this to the "classical Latin language"? I'm sure a *lot* could be said about progress in understanding pre-Latin influences. Also, when you say "understanding," are you referring to the literal meaning of a text or other things, e.g. cultural context?

Comment: @brianpck Any kind of understanding. I restricted to classical Latin on purpose, but I can't give other restrictions since I don't know where progress has focused. (I might ask more questions like this with different focus later if this one works out.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is always difficult to make this kind of charts. I think that the best thing that has been done on Latin over the last decades was to start studying it from a more linguistic point of view. By linguistic approach I mean, among other things, the following:

- Studying Latin within its linguistic environment, i.e. that of the Old Italic languages (Faliscan, Umbrian, Oscan etc.): textual data are richer than before, and we have a better idea of the dialectal zones within the Italic linguistic area. For example, the authenticity of the Fibula Praenestina has been recently [proven](https://www.academia.edu/1290713/Scientists_declare_the_Fibula_Prenestina_and_its_inscription_to_be_genuine_beyond_any_reasonable_doubt_).
- Studying non-classical periods of Latin; thus, we understand better some historical details of Archaic Latin (such as that of Ennius, [one example](https://www.academia.edu/3644027/Sulla_prosodia_di_do_in_Ennio_ann._576_V2)); we have studied the Vulgar Latin of the Pompeian graffiti, a good source of information about the evolutive processes that were happening on the edge of the Romance era (see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=aH1fAAAAMAAJ&q=isbn:2252023600&dq=isbn:2252023600&hl=la&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRkMayiPLSAhWClxoKHbXqArQQ6AEIGTAA)).
- Making sense of what ancient Roman grammarians were saying about their own language. Thus, some obscurities have been nicely explained; see, for example, [this brilliant explanation](https://scholar.google.it/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=it&user=tEdT5gMAAAAJ&cstart=20&pagesize=80&authuser=3&citation_for_view=tEdT5gMAAAAJ:eQOLeE2rZwMC) of the meaning of Nigidius' term *casus interrogandi*. The linguistic analysis of the *Appendix Probi* is another famous example in this respect.

A disclaimer: I am a linguist, not a philologist, so most probably I am missing many important discoveries made in Latin philology proper.

Comment: @brianpck thank you for editing. Sometimes I just don't realize how bad is my English

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and welcome to the site!

Comment: And it is such an honor to have Professor Keidan from Rome here.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of the first quarter of 2017.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/79)