# Where does one find research on Latin?

Tags: resource-request, research

For high school, I am researching some changes in Latin, but finding good scientific sources or papers online is really hard. Locally also isn't an option: the library had nothing of use. Is there somewhere online where one can access papers on Latin (without an expensive membership)? I would like to look into my options before travelling to the library in the big city.

Comment: Have you seen the question ["How to find scholarly articles related to Latin?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1515/79)? It looks pretty similar, but I'm not sure if it's an exact duplicate. Can you elaborate on where your question stands in relation to the other one?

Comment: Hmm, I think it actually yields the same results I was trying to achieve. Weird, I thought I had checked the suggested articles.

Comment: No worries! The correct questions are not always easy to find. To make it easier to future users, I marked this question as a duplicate of the earlier one, so that anyone who manages to find this will automatically find the answers. (If you really want this deleted, it's possible, but I would consider it more useful to keep around as a pointer.)

Comment: That is fine. No need to delete it then.

Comment: What changes in Latin are you researching?

Comment: The disappearance of cases in the fifth and sixth century AD in 3 regions: mauretania caesariensis, hispania citerior and latium et campania. This was done by analysing inscription from that time period. Now we have been asked to back up some the changes we found with some literature, but the other question was really helpful and we actually have completed it by now.